# Mapping on a compact set

Tags: functions, compactness

let us assume $r \le i$ , $1 \le r \le f$ , $1 \le i \le k$ .

We are looking for a mapping (lets call it $b(i,r)$) on the compact set $$[1,kf - \frac{f(f-1)}{2} ]$$

for fixed $k$, and fixed $f$ with $f <k$ .

Do you see a (maybe bijectiv) mapping?

best regards

Comment: The limits of those parameters don't seem very clear.

Comment: Hello , Why isnt it clear ?

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. It would be better with $r \leq i$ after $1 \leq i \leq k$ because you had not defined the range of $i$ and you were already using it. But you should also be more specific about what maps you're looking for.

Comment: Yes , you're right! sorry for the confusion! I'am looking for a mapping similar to the following : $a(i,j)= \frac{(j-2)(j-2)}{2}$ maps $1 \le i <j \le k$ on $[1, \frac{k^2 -k}{2}]$. But i dont see a mapping i am looking for in my question above.

Comment: And of course its a Mapping on the Natural Numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that what you mean is a bijection
$$b:\{ (i,r) \in \mathbb{N}^2 : 1 \leq r \leq f \text{ and } r \leq i \leq k \} \to \left[1, kf - \frac{f(f-1)}{2}\right] \cap \mathbb{N},$$
and it's not difficult to check that both sets have the same number of elements and so this is possible, and actually we can make it so that what that map does is $b(i,r)$ counts the number of elements in the domain up until $(i,r)$ using the lexicographic order.
Specifically, let
$$b(i,r) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{i(i-1)}{2} + r &\text{if } i \leq f\\
\frac{f(f+1)}{2} + r + (i - f - 1) \cdot f &\text{if } i > f.
\end{cases}
$$
I suppose you can verify that it ranges from $b(1,1) = 1$ up to $b(k,f) = kf - \frac{f(f-1)}{2}$.
A picture of the domain may be very helpful.
Good luck!

Comment: Hello , i just tried it -- but i think it doesnt work : lets assume k=6 and f=2 , so $b(6,2)= 3+2+(6-2-1) = 8 $ ... so is the mapping wrong?

Comment: I think there was a missing factor in the displayed formula for $b(i,r)$. Edited and it should be ok, now.

Comment: oh yes :) now it works :D